# Active Directory logs parsing using grok is slow

Tags: java, parsing, active-directory, grok

I am new to grok.
I am trying to parse [Microsoft active directory logs](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4624) using grok parser.
I am using [java grok](https://github.com/thekrakken/java-grok) library.

logs looks like

```
<13> 10.200.3.7  10.20.211.15 07/04/2017 15:34:00 PM SERVER01 07/04/2017 15:34:00 PM  LogName=Security  SourceName=Microsoft Windows security auditing.  EventCode=4624  EventType=0  Type=Information  ComputerName=SERVER01.network.local  TaskCategory=Logon  OpCode=Info  RecordNumber=1809490942  Keywords=Audit Success  Message=An account was successfully logged on.      Subject:     Security ID:        S-1-0-0     Account Name:       User-330    Account Domain:     -       Logon ID:       0x0      Logon Type:            3      New Logon:       Security ID:        S-1-5-18    Account Name:       SERVER01$       Account Domain:     DOMAIN      Logon ID:       0x12393ab39     Logon GUID:     \{C893D0A2-6498-BBE3-560D-0A1088FA4D9E\}      Process Information:      Process ID:     0x0     Process Name:       -      Network Information:     Workstation Name:       Source Network Address: 1.68.4.213      Source Port:        57261      Detailed Authentication Information:     Logon Process:      Kerberos    Authentication Package: Kerberos    Transited Services: -       Package Name (NTLM only):   -       Key Length:     0      This event is generated when a logon session is created. It is generated on the computer that was accessed.      The subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.      The logon type field indicates the kind of logon that occurred. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).      The New Logon fields indicate the account for whom the new logon was created, i.e. the account that was logged on.      The network fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.      The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.      - Logon GUID is a unique identifier that can be used to correlate this event with a KDC event.      - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.      - Package name\
<13> 10.200.3.7  10.20.211.15 07/04/2017 15:34:00 PM SERVER01 07/04/2017 15:34:00 PM  LogName=Security  SourceName=Microsoft Windows security auditing.  EventCode=4624  EventType=0  Type=Information  ComputerName=SERVER01.network.local  TaskCategory=Logon  OpCode=Info  RecordNumber=1809490942  Keywords=Audit Success  Message=An account was successfully logged on.      Subject:     Security ID:        S-1-0-0     Account Name:       User-331    Account Domain:     -       Logon ID:       0x0      Logon Type:            3      New Logon:       Security ID:        S-1-5-18    Account Name:       SERVER01$       Account Domain:     DOMAIN      Logon ID:       0x12393ab39     Logon GUID:     \{C893D0A2-6498-BBE3-560D-0A1088FA4D9E\}      Process Information:      Process ID:     0x0     Process Name:       -      Network Information:     Workstation Name:       Source Network Address: 1.68.4.214      Source Port:        57261      Detailed Authentication Information:     Logon Process:      Kerberos    Authentication Package: Kerberos    Transited Services: -       Package Name (NTLM only):   -       Key Length:     0      This event is generated when a logon session is created. It is generated on the computer that was accessed.      The subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.      The logon type field indicates the kind of logon that occurred. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).      The New Logon fields indicate the account for whom the new logon was created, i.e. the account that was logged on.      The network fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.      The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.      - Logon GUID is a unique identifier that can be used to correlate this event with a KDC event.      - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.      - Package name\
```

My grok pattern is

```
\<%{USER:hField1}\> %{IPV4:hIp1}  %{IPV4:hIp2} %{DATESTAMP_12HOUR:hTime1;date;dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a} %{USER:hField2} %{DATESTAMP_12HOUR:hTime2;date;dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a}  LogName=%{USER:logname}%{SPACE}SourceName=%{GREEDYDATA:sourceName}%{SPACE}EventCode=%{GREEDYDATA:eventCode}%{SPACE}EventType=%{GREEDYDATA:eventType}%{SPACE}Type=%{GREEDYDATA:typeField}%{SPACE} ComputerName=%{GREEDYDATA:computerName}%{SPACE}TaskCategory=%{GREEDYDATA:taskCategory}%{SPACE}OpCode=%{GREEDYDATA:opCode}%{SPACE}RecordNumber=%{GREEDYDATA:recordNumber}%{SPACE}Keywords=%{GREEDYDATA:keywords}%{SPACE}Message=%{NON_DOT_DELIMITER:message}.%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:jsonData}
```

The problem is that it is very slow as compared to my custom java parser.
My custom java parser takes 2.5 seconds to parse 50K records while parsing using grok pattern is taking 60 seconds for same data.

Is there any problem with my parser?

Comment: Are you using the same RegEx pattern to search for both?

Comment: samples logs I have shared contains two records and I am applying grok on per record basis.

Answer (score 0):

As with any regex you will gain speed ups when your regex interpreter has to guess less. So you might get good gains when using anchors `^` (start of line) and `$` (end of line) around your grok pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Is your custom Java parser uses Java regex ? Please take a look an issue opened [here](https://github.com/thekrakken/java-grok/issues/75) in your grok library github project. Seems there are some changes going on.